# How to setup lowerlimit and upperlimits if you only know the class midpoints in R?

Tags: r, statistics

I have the following data frame containing class midpoints for which I want to create  upper limits and lower limits.

`classmdpoint <- c(0, 100, 250, 300, 350, 500, 700, 850, 950, 1100, 1250, 1650, 2100, 2700, 3300, 4200, 5400, 10000)`

First I have tried to add the variable lower limit by the following code:

```
dfwagecmp %>%
  group_by(classmdpoint) %>%
  mutate(lowerlimit = classmdpoint -(classmdpoint - lag(classmdpoint, default = first(0),order_by = classmdpoint))/2))
```

This gives me the following ouput which is incorrect.

```
   classmdpoint lowerlimit  
          <dbl>      <dbl>   
 1            0          0      
 2          100         50      
 3          250        125      
 4          300        150      
 5          350        175      
 6          500        250      
 7          700        350      
 8          850        425      
 9          950        475      
10         1100        550     
11         1250        625
```

It should give me something like this:

```
         classmdpoint lowerlimit  
          <dbl>      <dbl>   
 1            0          0      
 2          100         50      
 3          250        175      
 4          300        275      
 5          350        325
```

Any solution to this problem? And how should I code to get the output for the upper limit?

Comment: Can you supply some example data from `dfwagecmp`? Using your `classmdpoint` data gives the expected results, so might be something in the group_by stage that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `group_by`, you need to half the difference between successive values, which you can achieve by using `diff(..) / 2` and simply subtracting that from existing midpoint:

```
lower = classmdpoint-c(0,diff(classmdpoint)/2)
cbind(classmdpoint,lower)

      classmdpoint lower
 [1,]            0     0
 [2,]          100    50
 [3,]          250   175
 [4,]          300   275
 [5,]          350   325
 [6,]          500   425
 [7,]          700   600
 [8,]          850   775
 [9,]          950   900
[10,]         1100  1025
[11,]         1250  1175
[12,]         1650  1450
[13,]         2100  1875
[14,]         2700  2400
[15,]         3300  3000
[16,]         4200  3750
[17,]         5400  4800
[18,]        10000  7700
```